# What should change for the this code to correctly identify balanced Trees?

Tags: swift, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm doing [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/).
I already have done another implementation that uses a height function. That works.

I have this other implementation. Visually when I look at the problem I get why it won't work. But I can't find words to write it down for myself as to why it doesn't work.
It fails on its 214th test for `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, null, null, 4, 4]`

```
class Solution {
    // for every node I have to go 2 levels down. 
    // if left existed, then see if right exists, and traverse down 
    // if left existed and had children but right didn't exist then return `false`
    // or if right existed and had children but left didn't exist then return `false`
    func isBalanced(_ root: TreeNode?) -> Bool {
        if let left = root?.left {
            if let right = root?.right {
                return isBalanced(left) && isBalanced(right)
            } else if left.left != nil || left.right != nil {
                    return false
                }
        } else if let right = root?.right {
            if root?.left == nil {
                if right.left != nil || right.right != nil {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

To be clear I'm not looking for alternate solutions. I'm only trying to understand why the current implementation doesn't work.

Comment: On "level 2", you find both left and right an return `isBalanced(left) && isBalanced(right)` - which both hold and are a necessary condition (subtrees of *every* node differ in height by no more than 1). But it is not sufficient, as their height may - you guess it - differ by two (as here) or more. Just return the height of each subtree, find min, max & difference thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for instance this tree:

```
                  8
                /   \
               4     9
             /   \
            2     6
           / \   / \
          1   3 5   7
```

Starting at the root, the execution of this code will enter the inner `if` block:

```
    if let left = root?.left {
        if let right = root?.right {
            return isBalanced(left) && isBalanced(right)
```

...and the two recursive calls will return true, because indeed those subtrees are balanced on their own, and so this tree will be identified as balanced. Yet it is clear this is not the case.

You will really need to retrieve the heights of the subtrees and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an alternate solutions, I just removed unnecessary check...

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(left, right) {
        this.left = left
        this.right = right
    }
    isEndNode() { return this.left == null && this.right == null; }
    isBalanced() {
        if (this.isEndNode()) return true;

        if (this.left && this.right)
            return this.left.isBalanced() && this.right.isBalanced();

        return false
    }
}
let node = (left, right) => new TreeNode(left, right);

let root1 = node(node(node(), node()), node(node(), node()))
let root2 = node(node(node(), node()), node(node(), null))
let root3 = node(node(null, node()), node(node(), node()))

console.log(root1.isBalanced()) // true
console.log(root2.isBalanced()) // false
console.log(root3.isBalanced()) // false
```

Comment: Two unwanted results out of three. Add `let root4 = node(null, node(node(node(), node()), node(node(), node()))`.

Comment: Two unwanted results ???

Comment: `For this problem, a height-balanced binary tree is defined as[a]tree in which the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more than 1.`